# Asignar valor a variable tmpdata desde función javascript

Tags: javascript, mvc, formularios, views

Tengo la siguiente duda:
¿Es posible rellenar la variable TempData desde una función javascript? La razón de querer realizar esto es para enviar valores desde una vista a otra.

Esta es mi función Javascript:

```
function ALINEAS_create() 
{
    alert("Botón pulsado")
    var NumeroID = document.querySelector('#Numero').value;
    var NombreID = document.querySelector('#Nombre').value;
    var ICCID = document.querySelector('#ICC').value;
    var PUKID = document.querySelector('#PUK').value;
    var OperadorID = document.querySelector('#Operador').value;
    var ObservacionesID = document.querySelector('#Observaciones').value;
    var FechaAltaID = document.querySelector('#FechaAlta').value;
    var ExtensionID = document.querySelector('#Extension').value;
    var FechaBajaID = document.querySelector('#FechaBaja').value;
    formulario = document.getElementById('ALINEAS');
    formulario.setAttribute('action', '/Lineas/create');

    /* 
    Y me gustaría poder hacer lo siguiente:
    TempData["Numero"] = NumeroID;
    TempData["Nombre"] = NombreID;
    ... etc
    */
}
```

¿Existe una forma mas simple de enviar valores entre vistas? Basicamente quiero hacerlo así porque introduzco los datos en un formulario pero la validación de los mismos quiero que se realice en la vista de *create*, por poner un ejemplo.

Las dos vistas que tengo son:

La vista que desde la que quiero introducir los datos, con URL: *https://localhost:44370/Lineas*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La vista en la que quiero que se introduzcan los datos, con URL: *https://localhost:44370/Lineas/create*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías crear una variable como pretendes, pero al cambiar la página se borrará. La solución es guardar los valores en el LocalStorage del navegador como JSON, o enviarlos al backend y que la página se genere con los datos ya introducidos.

Answer (score 0):

En la página origen
Para generar la dirección destino debemos saber cómo se codifican una lista de variables para introducirlas en una URL. Esto se hace poniendo un símbolo de interrogación (?) detrás del nombre del archivo al que se pasan las variables (que en nuestro caso será destino.html). Después de ese símbolo viene la lista de variables, separada por el símbolo ampersand (&). Cada elemento de dicha lista consiste en el nombre de la variable, el símbolo de igualdad (=) y el valor de la variable.

Sin embargo, y como en una URL podemos incluir muy pocos caracteres, algunos de los valores de las variables tendrán que estar codificados. Por ejemplo, no puede haber espacios en una dirección en formato URL. ¿Cómo incluimos entonces los espacios de nuestras variables tipo cadena? Sustituyendolos por %20, que es el equivalente al espacio dentro de la codificación URL. Así por ejemplo, si tenemos dos variables llamadas var1 y var2 cuyos valores son, respectivamente, 3 y "Hola, que tal", la URL resultante será:

destino.html?var1=3&var2=Hola%2C%20que%20tal

Javascript ofrece una pareja de funciones que permiten codificar y descodificar una cadena a formato URL. Son escape y unescape. Por lo tanto, ya tenemos todo lo que nos hace falta para enviar variables. Para que sea más sencillo utilizaremos una función que, al ser llamada, realice el envío.

function pasarVariables(pagina, nombres) {
  pagina +="?";
  nomVec = nombres.split(",");
  for (i=0; i

El método funciona añadiendo a la variable pagina el texto necesario para pasar las variables y, finalmente, redirigirse a la dirección resultado de esos añadidos. Por eso, lo primero es añadir el símbolo de interrogación. Luego crea un vector con los nombres de las variables utilizando el método split. El bucle añade a cada iteración el nombre de la variable, el símbolo de igualdad, el valor de dicha variable codificado en URL y el ampersand. Por último, una vez terminado el bucle, se borra el último ampersand que ya nos sobra.
Para utilizar esta función, la llamaremos desde un enlace:

Pulse
aquí

Página destino

Una vez que sabemos enviar las variables, tendremos que escribir también un poco de código para recibirlas desde la página destino. Este es el código que colocaremos en la cabecera de la página, antes que el resto del código, para que podamos utilizar las variables cuanto antes:

cadVariables = location.search.substring(1,location.search.length);
arrVariables = cadVariables.split("&");
for (i=0; i

Lo que hacemos en la primera línea es eliminar la interrogación del texto que viene detrás del nombre de la página en la URL. Para lograrlo, escogemos una subcadena de location.search, que es la propiedad que contiene ese texto.

Luego, convertimos esa cadena en un vector que tiene una pareja "variable=valor" en cada uno de sus elementos. Entonces, recorremos cada elemento de dicho vector, creamos un vector temporal que contiene en su primer elemento el nombre de la variable y en el segundo el valor y, utilizando la función eval, creamos la variable asignandola a su valor.

Por último, indicar que dentro del bucle existe una condición que comprueba si la variable es o no numérica para, al hacer la asignación, decidir si encierra o no el valor entre comillas.

Comment: Perdona, se ha cortado el código que ponías, puede ser? esque no termino de ver como debería de ser el string que monto. Muchas gracias!